# How to enable HDR in windows with a multi screen set up

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdr

I have 3 monitors, 1 HDR capable and 2 not.

If I enable HDR in the windows options, it works fine on the HDR capable one, but the other two are waaaaay over bright, faded and difficult to read.

Is there a way to only enable HDR on the HDR capable monitor.

[pic of HDR and advanced colour settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhWK.png)

[picture of HDR and advanced colour option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6UD.png)

**EDIT**

system: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

build: Version  10.0.16299 Build 16299

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I have edited the query, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only enable HDR on the HDR capable monitor.

It is indeed possible.  However, it does appear that it will be possible if you are running Windows 10 1709.

> You might need to adjust the relative brightness of SDR and HDR content for your HDR-capable display. This is because a display interprets an HDR and SDR signal differently, and the results will vary by make and model.
>
> 1. Select the **Start** button, then select **Settings > System > Display**.
> 2. If you have multiple displays connected to your PC, select the HDR-capable display under **Select and rearrange displays**, and then
>    move the Settings app window to the HDR display that you’re adjusting
> 3. On the **Display** settings screen, select **Windows HD Color** settings.
> 4. Under **SDR content appearance**, drag the slider to get the right balance for brightness between HDR and SDR content.

Source: [HDR and WCG color settings in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4040263/windows-10-hdr-advanced-color-settings)

> Problem: All standard dynamic range (SDR) content and apps appear too bright or too dark on an HDR-capable display.
>
> Solution: Since the brightness of SDR content is already set, the SDR content appearance setting will change the brightness of HDR content relative to the brightness of SDR content.

Setting the SDR brightness level on all your monitors should solve your problem.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but there is no such menu under the select and rearrage displays page. There is a HDR and advanced colour settings sub menu, but it doesnt have any options in it ( I put a picture in the question).

Comment: also the yellow in your reply becomes effectively white. I have tried varying the manual brightness and contrast on the SDR monitors, but this doenst help the colour situation and it looks very washed out. The windows HD colour settings menu is not their.

Comment: @Laurence_jj - I quoted Microsoft directly, so the instructions are valid, but they might only apply to specific versions of Window 10.  Be sure you are running Windows 10 version 1903.  If adjusting the SDR color does not solve your problem then I have no other suggestions.